# C# Filling Third Array With Items From First Two. Leaving Out Duplicates

Tags: c#, arrays

Looking for some help in figuring this out.  I have two arrays of names.  What I need to do is bubble sort them (which I have done, see code below), and populate the third array with the values from the first two array, leaving out duplicates, and not sorting the third array.  Below is my example code, which completely works for what I am doing, except I need to use a loop to fill in the third array (logical exercise).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MergeArray
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] names1 = { "Bob", "John", "Bill", "Sandy", "Betty", "Bart", "Patty" };
        string[] names2 = { "Andy", "Chris", "Bill", "Walter" };
        string[] names3 = new string[names1.Length + names2.Length];

        string temp;

        foreach (string i in names1)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < names1.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                if (String.Compare(names1[j], names1[j+1]) > 0)
                {
                    temp = names1[j];
                    names1[j] = names1[j + 1];
                    names1[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        foreach (string i in names2)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < names2.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                if (String.Compare(names2[j], names2[j + 1]) > 0)
                {
                    temp = names2[j];
                    names2[j] = names2[j + 1];
                    names2[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        names1.CopyTo(names3, 0);
        names2.CopyTo(names3, names1.Length);

        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, names3.Distinct().ToArray()));
            Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
}
```

In the end, this code does what I need it to do, which is populate the third array with "Bart, Betty, Bill, Bob, John, Patty, Sandy, Andy, Chris, Walter".  It doesn't fill in the duplicate "Bill" and it just adds the two arrays together, without sorting the third (which is what I need to do).  What I need help with is turning the part where I fill in the third array into a loop instead of the:

```
        names1.CopyTo(names3, 0);
        names2.CopyTo(names3, names1.Length);

        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, names3.Distinct().ToArray()));
```

Please help me out to understand what I need to do here.

Comment: What trouble are you having with turning it into a loop?

Comment: You can remove the inner loops, arrays have a `.Contains` method to determine if the array contains an item...

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to [merge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393627/merging-two-sorted-arrays-into-a-third-one-can-be-done-in-on) two already sort arrays.  Since you've already gone to the trouble of bubble sorting, just apply a modified merge operation (that excludes duplicates).

Comment: You could try with the [`union`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb341731(v=vs.110).aspx) method

Comment: ryanyuyu, that's what I was going to do.  It would by muuuuuch easier if I could.  But I have to do it outside of the loops.  Don't ask me why, just the way it's needed.  I really don't understand why myself.

Comment: @PhilJ you can still do so in a third loop following the two sorts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your bubble sort successfully sorts you elements, you can use a modified merge operation to put together the final array.  Basically a merge takes two sorted arrays and puts them together by comparing the "top" elements of each array and moving that one to the composite array.

You would just have to check for duplicate while you are doing this.  And since your arrays are both sorted, all duplicates will clump together into groups, so you would only need to keep track of the most recent duplicate.

Something like this (which is very verbose and heavily commented) could work:

```
public static string[] MergeNoDuplicates(string[] left, string[] right)
{
    var mergedArray = new string[left.Length + right.Length];

    //since the arrays are sorted, we only need to keep track of the most recent duplicate
    string duplicateChecker = null; 

    int mergeIndex = 0; 
    int l = 0; //index for left array
    int r = 0; //index for right array
    //while there are more element in at least one of the two arrays
    bool leftHasElements = l < left.Length;
    bool rightHasElements = r < right.Length;
    while (leftHasElements && rightHasElements)
    {
        string leftString = left[l];
        string rightString = right[r];
        int comparisonResult = leftString.CompareTo(rightString);
        if (comparisonResult < 0) //left string comes before right string
        {
            //not a duplicate
            if (leftString.CompareTo(duplicateChecker) != 0)
            {
                mergedArray[mergeIndex] = leftString;
                mergeIndex++;
                duplicateChecker = leftString;
            }
            //regardless of whether it's a duplicate move onto the next element
            l++;
        }
        else if (comparisonResult > 0) //right string comes before left
        {
            if (rightString.CompareTo(duplicateChecker) != 0)
            {
                mergedArray[mergeIndex] = rightString;
                mergeIndex++;
                duplicateChecker = rightString;
            }

            r++;
        }
        else //comparisonResult by default == 0
        {
            //since they are the same string, just insert one (if needed), but increment both arrays
            if (leftString.CompareTo(duplicateChecker) != 0)
            {
                mergedArray[mergeIndex] = leftString;
                mergeIndex++;
                duplicateChecker = leftString;
            }

            l++;
            r++;
        }

        leftHasElements = l < left.Length;
        rightHasElements = r < right.Length;
    }

    //now at least one of the arrays is empty, so add all of the remaining
    //non-duplicate elements of the other to the array
    //if either is false, the loop won't execute in the first place
    while (leftHasElements)
    {
        string leftString = left[l];
        if (leftString.CompareTo(duplicateChecker) != 0)
        {
            mergedArray[mergeIndex] = leftString;
            mergeIndex++;
            duplicateChecker = leftString;
        }

        l++;
        leftHasElements = l < left.Length;
    }

    while (rightHasElements)
    {
        string rightString = right[r];
        if (rightString.CompareTo(duplicateChecker) != 0)
        {
            mergedArray[mergeIndex] = rightString;
            mergeIndex++;
            duplicateChecker = rightString;
        }

        r++;
        rightHasElements = r < right.Length;
    }

    //now remove null elements (if needed) and return
    //alternatively, just use LINQ's TakeWhile and ToArray
    if (mergeIndex == mergedArray.Length)
        return mergedArray;
    var returnedArray = new string[mergeIndex];
    Array.Copy(mergedArray, returnedArray, mergeIndex);
    return returnedArray;
}
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zp9Q2K)

Comment: +1 using the one string as a duplicatechecker given the sorted inputs is better than my suggested hashmap for this purpose.

Comment: @Mr.Mindor Yeah, I'm just intrigued that even for this kind of question we came up with like multiple ways to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ohh the power of `linq`!

```
string[] names1 = { "Bob", "John", "Bill", "Sandy", "Betty", "Bart", "Patty" };
string[] names2 = { "Andy", "Chris", "Bill", "Walter" };

string[] names3 = names1.Union(names2).Distinct().ToArray();
```

Comment: That doesnt account for if an array started out with duplicates

Comment: It does though.  Here's [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341731(v=vs.100).aspx), and the example they use seems to remove any duplicate, regardless of where it came from.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I have to do it in loops.  something like (please forgive me, I don't know how to use the code editor in comments  foreach(var a in names1){ foreach(var b in names2){ if (a !=b){//add to names3)}  I'm assuming something like that, but I think that would only account for adding in the items from names1 to names3, and it might get rid of "Bill" altogether.

Answer (score 1):

As ryanyuyu suggested, use a modified merge operation.
This will come after you have already sorted them.

```
int m = 0;
int n = 0;
while ((m < names1.Count) && (n < names1.Count))
{
    int comparison = String.Compare(names1[m], names2[n]);
    if (comparison < 0) // names1[m] is before names2[n]
    {
        names3.Add(names1[m]);
        m = m + 1;
    }
    else if (comparison > 1) //names2[n] is before names1[m]
    {
        names3.Add(names2[n]);
        n = n + 1;
    }
    else //names1[m] is equal to names2[n], only add one.
    {
        names3.Add(names1[m]);
        m = m + 1;
        n = n + 1;
    }
}
//either names1 or names2 ran out of entries. fill names3 with whatever is left
while (m < names1.Count)
{
    names3.Add(names1[m]);
    m = m + 1;
}
while (n < names2.Count)
{
    names3.Add(names2[n]);
    n = n + 1;
}
```

If it is possible the original arrays might themselves contain duplicates, you can track which values have been added using a HashSet.

```
List<string> names1 = new List<string>();
List<string> names2 = new List<string>();
List<string> names3 = new List<string>();
var included = new HashSet<string>();
int m = 0;
int n = 0;
while ((m < names1.Count) && (n < names1.Count))
{
    int comparison = String.Compare(names1[m], names2[n]);
    if (comparison < 0)
    {
        if(included.Add(names1[m]))
        {
            names3.Add(names1[m]);
        }
        m = m + 1;
    }
    else if (comparison > 1)
    {
        if (included.Add(names2[n]))
        {
            names3.Add(names2[n]);    
        }
        n = n + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        names3.Add(names1[m]);
        m = m + 1;
        n = n + 1;
    }
}
while (m < names1.Count)
{
    if (included.Add(names1[m]))
    {
        names3.Add(names1[m]);
    }
    m = m + 1;
}
while (n < names2.Count)
{
    if (included.Add(names2[n]))
    {
        names3.Add(names2[n]);
    }
    n = n + 1;
}
```

Of course at this point you might as well make `names3` a `HashSet` and skip the extra checks. The only benefit we have for keeping `included` separate is that `names3` retains the sorted order. There is no guarantee this will be true if names3 itself were the HashSet and you did names3.ToArray() at the end.

Comment: This works if neither input array has duplicates, but this is the general idea.

Comment: true is names1 or names2 have duplicates themselves the result will have duplicates. this will only skip entries of names2 that are also in names1.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest copying to a List<>, using "Distinct":

Use "AddRange()" to add the second array.

Use "Distinct()" to eliminate the duplicates,

Finally, convert the list back to an array.

EXAMPLE:

```
List<string> myList = myArray.Cast<string>().ToList();
myList.AddRange(mySecondArray);
string[] myNewArray = myList.Distinct().toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();
names.AddRange(names1);
names.AddRange(names2);
names.Sort();
string[] names3 = names.Distinct().ToArray();
```

Comment: Because this is almost certainly homework, and they are trying to teach him how to use loops.

Comment: @pquest Yup.  It's not homework, though.  It's an extra exercise I'm working on because I'm trying to build up my confidence, since I'm not too great with them.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use .Union:

```
string[] names1 = { "Bob", "John", "Bill", "Sandy", "Betty", "Bart", "Patty" };
string[] names2 = { "Andy", "Chris", "Bill", "Walter" };

string[] names3 = names1.Union(names2).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a loop like this:

```
int names1I = 0;
int names2I = 0;

for(int i = 0; names1I < names1.Length && names2I < names2.Length; i++)
{
    while(names1I < names1.Length && names3.Contains(names1[names1I]))
      names1I++;
    while(names2I < names2.Length && names3.Contains(names2[names2I]))
      names2I++;

    if(names1I == names1.Length) //if you have already reached the end of array 1, you have to use array 2
      names3[i] = names2[names2I++];
    else if(names2I == names2.Length) //if you have already reached the end of array 2, you have to use array 1
      names3[i] = names1[names1I++];
    else //else take the smaller of the 2 possible values
      names3[i] = (names1[names1I] <= names2[names2I]) ? names1[names1I++] : names2[names2I++];
}
```

Comment: how will you know what size to make names3 if you don't yet know how many duplicates there are? better to make your condition `names1I < names1.Length && names2I < names2.Length`